# How to iterate over values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key and value pairs. Each key could have multiple values, for example the dictionary could be something like this:

```
    enh_166084:['AC002454.1', 'RN7SL7P']
    enh_341666:['MYOM1', 'RP13-270P17.2', 'SNORA70']
```

Now, I want to iterate over keys and write its corresponding values to a txt file, each value on a single line, some thing like this:

```
    AC002454.1
    RN7SL7P
    MYOM1
    RP13-270P17.2
    ......
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the dictionary `itervalues()` method:

```
for value in your_dict.itervalues():
    # Since the values are lists, we have to enumerate those too:
    for item in value:
        output_file.write(item)
        output_file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each key and then over each value:

```
for key in dictionary: # For each key
    for value in dictionary[key]: # For each value in the dictionary under that key
        # Do something with the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might extract the values as a nested list, flatten that, then loop over it:

```
import itertools
chain = itertools.chain(*mydict.values())
for i in list(chain):
    output_file.write(item)
    output_file.write("\n")
```